# why is my sequence file being read twice in my hadoop mapper class?

Tags: hadoop, mapper

i have a SequenceFile with 1264 records. each key is unique for each record. my problem is that my mapper seems to be reading this file twice or it is being read twice. for sanity checking, i have written a little utility class to read the SequenceFile and indeed, there are only 1264 records (i.e. SequenceFile.Reader).

in my reducer, i should only get 1 record per Iterable, however, when i iterate over the iterable (Iterator), i get 2 records per Key (always 2 per key, and not 1 or 3 or something else per Key).

the logging output of my Job is below. i am not sure why, but why is it that the "Total input paths to process" is 2? when i run my Job, i tried -Dmapred.input.dir=/data and also -Dmapred.input.dir=/data/part-r-00000, but still, the total paths to process is 2.

any ideas is appreciated.

```
12/03/01 05:28:30 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
12/03/01 05:28:30 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000000_0' done.
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task:attempt_local_0001_m_000001_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task 'attempt_local_0001_m_000001_0' done.
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 2 sorted segments
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 2 segments left of total size: 307310 bytes
12/03/01 05:28:31 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
12/03/01 05:28:32 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task:attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of commiting
12/03/01 05:28:32 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner:
12/03/01 05:28:32 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
12/03/01 05:28:32 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
12/03/01 05:28:32 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' to results
12/03/01 05:28:32 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
12/03/01 05:28:32 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Task 'attempt_local_0001_r_000000_0' done.
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 100%
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 12
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:   FileSystemCounters
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_READ=1320214
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=1275041
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce Framework
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input groups=1264
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine output records=0
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map input records=2528
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce shuffle bytes=0
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce output records=2528
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=5056
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=301472
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Combine input records=0
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output records=2528
12/03/01 05:28:33 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Reduce input records=2528
```

My mapper class is very simple. It reads in a text file. To each line, it appends "m" to the line.

```
public class MyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {

 private static final Log _log = LogFactory.getLog(MyMapper.class);

 @Override
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  String s = (new StringBuilder()).append(value.toString()).append("m").toString();
  context.write(key, new Text(s));
  _log.debug(key.toString() + " => " + s);
 }
}
```

My reducer class is also very simple. It simply appends "r" to the line.

```
public class MyReducer extends Reducer<LongWritable, Text, LongWritable, Text> {

private static final Log _log = LogFactory.getLog(MyReducer.class);

@Override
public void reduce(LongWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
 for(Iterator<Text> it = values.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  Text txt = it.next();
  String s = (new StringBuilder()).append(txt.toString()).append("r").toString();
  context.write(key, new Text(s));
  _log.debug(key.toString() + " => " + s);
  }
 }
}
```

my Job class is as follows.

```
public class MyJob extends Configured implements Tool {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new MyJob(), args);
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
 Configuration conf = getConf();
 Path input = new Path(conf.get("mapred.input.dir"));
 Path output = new Path(conf.get("mapred.output.dir"));

 System.out.println("input = " + input);
 System.out.println("output = " + output);

 Job job = new Job(conf, "dummy job");
 job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
 job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
 job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
 job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

 job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
 job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input);
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);

 job.setJarByClass(MyJob.class);

 return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
 }
}
```

my input data looks like the following.

```
T, T
T, T
T, T
F, F
F, F
F, F
F, F
T, F
F, T
```

after running my Job, i get an output like the following.

```
0   T, Tmr
0   T, Tmr
6   T, Tmr
6   T, Tmr
12  T, Tmr
12  T, Tmr
18  F, Fmr
18  F, Fmr
24  F, Fmr
24  F, Fmr
30  F, Fmr
30  F, Fmr
36  F, Fmr
36  F, Fmr
42  T, Fmr
42  T, Fmr
48  F, Tmr
48  F, Tmr
```

did i do something wrong with setting up my Job? i tried the following way to run my Job, and in this approach, the file only gets read once. why is this? the System.out.println(inpath) and System.out.println(outpath) values are identical! help?

```
public class MyJob2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: MyJob2 <in> <out>");
      System.exit(2);
    }

    String sInput = args[0];
    String sOutput = args[1];

    Path input = new Path(sInput);
    Path output = new Path(sOutput);

    System.out.println("input = " + input);
    System.out.println("output = " + output);

    Job job = new Job(conf, "dummy job");
    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(LongWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setMapperClass(MyMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MyReducer.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);

    job.setJarByClass(MyJob2.class);

    int result = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    System.exit(result);
 }
}
```

Comment: hmm.. can't answer this without any code. I guess it would be useful if you can post the run() method where you are configuring the job..

Comment: It would also be helpful to post the job-conf.xml file if you still have access to it.

Comment: sorry i took a while, i've added dummy code that is similar to the one i actually use. even with the dummy code, if you copy/paste/build jar and run it, you will still see that each line is being read twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got help from the hadoop mailing list. my problem was with the line below.

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input);
```

this line simply appends input back to config. after commenting this line out, the input file is read only once now. in fact, i also commented out the other line,

```
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output);
```

and everything still works.

Comment: While I have tried that.... getting the following error ....    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job

Comment: Note that he does set the input path twice, both on the commandline with the -D command and adds the path again with addInputPath. So you are forced to choose either one of these..

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, but for a different reason: linux apparently created a hidden copy of my input file (~input.txt), so that's a second way of getting this error..