# My Input file is being read twice by the mapper in MapReduce of Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am facing the problem while write MapReduce Program, my input file is being read twice by the program. already have gone through this [why is my sequence file being read twice in my hadoop mapper class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514710/why-is-my-sequence-file-being-read-twice-in-my-hadoop-mapper-class) answer, but unfortunately it did not help

My Mapper class is:

```
package com.siddu.mapreduce.csv;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class SidduCSVMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> 
{

    IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text line,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter report)
            throws IOException 
    {
        String lineCSV= line.toString();

        String[] tokens = lineCSV.split(";");

        output.collect(new Text(tokens[2]), one);
    }

}
```

And My Reducer class is:

```
package com.siddu.mapreduce.csv;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class SidduCSVReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> 
{

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> inputFrmMapper,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException 
    {
        System.out.println("In reducer the key is:"+key.toString());

        int relationOccurance=0;
        while(inputFrmMapper.hasNext())
        {
            IntWritable intWriteOb = inputFrmMapper.next();
            int val = intWriteOb.get();

            relationOccurance += val;

        }

        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(relationOccurance));

    }



}
```

And finally My Driver class is:

```
package com.siddu.mapreduce.csv;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class SidduCSVMapReduceDriver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        JobClient client = new JobClient();
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(com.siddu.mapreduce.csv.SidduCSVMapReduceDriver.class);

        conf.setJobName("Siddu CSV Reader 1.0");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);

        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(com.siddu.mapreduce.csv.SidduCSVMapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(com.siddu.mapreduce.csv.SidduCSVReducer.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        client.setConf(conf);

        try
        {
            JobClient.runJob(conf);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you looking at and stating that input is being read twice? Can you share more details?

Comment: When i am trying to print the INPUT FILE details, in the MAPPER class,what i have observed is the same details are getting printed twice, but the funny part is: when i try to run in the hadoop SINGLE NODE cluster, everything is working fine, i am getting this PROBLEM, when i am trying to run the SAME as the JAVA APP in the eclipse. please shed some light on this

Comment: Do job counters tell same? for example, when looking at map input records read is it double than actual number of lines in csv file?

Comment: yes you got it right, was having the same problem when i am using the app in the eclipse, but when i ARCHIVE it AS JAR and run it on HADOOP cluster, everything seem to work fine, but what i am unable to understand is why is this discrepancy?

Comment: hmm...when running via eclispe does "Total input paths to process" say 2 as well like reported in other question?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, thats what is happening, what can be the reason?

Comment: Have you edited the data file?  Some editors leave a backup copy of the file in the same directory. Hadoop would treat that copy like a second file.

Comment: Hi Chris, I did edit the file few times, but when as i have mentioned in my above comments, it is running properly when i am trying to run it using HADOOP DFS.. but when i am trying to run as a normal JAVA APP from eclipse, i am facing the problem..

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that hadoop spawns multiple attempts of a task, usually two for each mapper. If you see log file output twice, that's probably the reason.