# MapReduce: two splits (execution of map method) for one line input file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I developed a mapReduce program to count and log into a request file the number of request by 30 minutes and the most searched word in this period.

My input file is:

```
01_11_2012 12_02_10 132.227.045.028 life
02_11_2012 02_52_10 132.227.045.028 restaurent+kitchen
03_11_2012 12_32_10 132.227.045.028 guitar+music
04_11_2012 13_52_10 132.227.045.028 book+music
05_11_2012 12_22_10 132.227.045.028 animal+life
05_11_2012 12_22_10 132.227.045.028 history
```

DD_MM_YYYY | HH_MM_SS | ip | searched words

My output file should diplay something like:

```
between 02h30 and 2h59 restaurent 1  
between 13h30 and 13h59 book 1
between 12h00 and 12h29 life 3  
between 12h30 and 12h59 guitar 1
```

First line : restaurent is the most seek word for the period between 02h30 and 2h59 and 1 represent the number of request.

My problem is that I get redundent map execution for the same line. So I test the program with the following input (1 line in my file).

`01_11_2012 12_02_10 132.227.045.028 life`

When I debug with eclipse line per line, putting a break point on the following map line.

```
context.write(key, result);
```

My program pass two time on this line and write two time the same information for the unique input line.

I am stuck at this point and I don't know why I get 2 map task, since I should have only one split regarding my input.

The program is as follows.
(sorry for my English)

```
package fitec.lab.booble;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class BoobleByMinutes {

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        private final int TIME_INDEX = 1;
        private final int WORDS_INDEX = 3;

        @Override
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String[] attributesTab = value.toString().split(" ");

            Text reduceKey = new Text();
            Text words = new Text();

            String time = attributesTab[TIME_INDEX];
            String[] timeSplitted = time.split("_");

            String heures = timeSplitted[0];
            String minutes = timeSplitted[1];

            if (29 < Integer.parseInt(minutes)) {
                reduceKey.set("entre " + heures + "h30 et " + heures + "h59");
            } else {
                reduceKey.set("entre " + heures + "h00 et " + heures + "h29");
            }
            words.set(attributesTab[WORDS_INDEX]);
            context.write(reduceKey, words);
        }
    }

    public static class PriceSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> groupedWords, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Text result = new Text();
            int requestCount = 0;
            Map<String, Integer> firstWordAndRequestCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            for (Text words : groupedWords) {
                ++requestCount;
                String wordsString = words.toString().replace("+", "--");
                System.out.println(wordsString.toString());
                String[] wordTab = wordsString.split("--");
                for (String word : wordTab) {

                    if (firstWordAndRequestCount.containsKey(word)) {
                        Integer integer = firstWordAndRequestCount.get(word) + 1;
                        firstWordAndRequestCount.put(word, integer);
                    } else {
                        firstWordAndRequestCount.put(word, new Integer(1));
                    }
                }
            }

            ValueComparator valueComparator = new ValueComparator(firstWordAndRequestCount);
            TreeMap<String, Integer> sortedProductsSale = new TreeMap<String, Integer>(valueComparator);
            sortedProductsSale.putAll(firstWordAndRequestCount);
            result.set(sortedProductsSale.firstKey() + "__" + requestCount);
            context.write(key, result);
        }

        class ValueComparator implements Comparator<String> {
            Map<String, Integer> base;

            public ValueComparator(Map<String, Integer> base) {
                this.base = base;
            }

            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                if (base.get(a) >= base.get(b)) {
                    return -1;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Job job = new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job();
        job.setJarByClass(BoobleByMinutes.class);
        job.setJobName("Booble mot le plus recherché et somme de requete par tranche de 30 minutes");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        job.setJarByClass(BoobleByMinutes.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
//      job.setCombinerClass(PriceSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(PriceSumReducer.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

@Radim
Whene i Launch the jar with yarn into real hadoop i get number of split = 2

i put the log below

```
16/07/18 02:56:39 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/07/18 02:56:40 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/07/18 02:56:42 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.
16/07/18 02:56:42 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 2
16/07/18 02:56:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
16/07/18 02:56:43 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1468802929497_0002
16/07/18 02:56:44 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1468802929497_0002
16/07/18 02:56:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://moussa:8088/proxy/application_1468802929497_0002/
16/07/18 02:56:44 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1468802929497_0002
16/07/18 02:56:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1468802929497_0002 running in uber mode : false
16/07/18 02:56:56 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/07/18 02:57:14 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/07/18 02:57:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
16/07/18 02:57:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1468802929497_0002 completed successfully
16/07/18 02:57:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 49
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=66
        FILE: Number of bytes written=352628
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=278
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=31
        HDFS: Number of read operations=9
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2
    Job Counters 
        Launched map tasks=2
        Launched reduce tasks=1
        Data-local map tasks=2
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=29431
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=6783
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=29431
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=6783
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=29431
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=6783
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=30137344
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=6945792
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=2
        Map output records=2
        Map output bytes=56
        Map output materialized bytes=72
        Input split bytes=194
        Combine input records=0
        Combine output records=0
        Reduce input groups=1
        Reduce shuffle bytes=72
        Reduce input records=2
        Reduce output records=1
        Spilled Records=4
        Shuffled Maps =2
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=2
        GC time elapsed (ms)=460
        CPU time spent (ms)=2240
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=675127296
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=5682606080
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=529465344
    Shuffle Errors
        BAD_ID=0
        CONNECTION=0
        IO_ERROR=0
        WRONG_LENGTH=0
        WRONG_MAP=0
        WRONG_REDUCE=0
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=84
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=31
```

Comment: can you check in file if file has two lines with same time `grep '12_02_10' inputFile` ?

Comment: Try to run it in real Hadoop setup instead of using Eclipse that can do some unexpected things. I would suspect something like backup copy of a file from editor that can duplicate your input.

Comment: I have tried the command grep '12_02_10' myFile andit return one line.

Comment: Hi Radim 
i get strange result when i lauch the jar file with yarn in real hadoop. the job stuck at map 0% reduce 0% and suddenly log me off of my ubuntu session.  so when i login i had to relaunch my daemons...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the solution from this link: [why is my sequence file being read twice in my hadoop mapper class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514710/why-is-my-sequence-file-being-read-twice-in-my-hadoop-mapper-class)

I did not see that i get Total input paths to process : 2 in my log.
as they say in the link i just needed to comment the line

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
```

I don't understand the comment "this line simply appends input back to config"
can anyone explain please
any ideas is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your main(job) method these lines are duplicated:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
```

also:`job.setJarByClass(BoobleByMinutes.class);`

but this line should be causing the duplicate input: `FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));`

so your main method should be:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Job job = new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job();
        job.setJarByClass(BoobleByMinutes.class);
        job.setJobName("Booble mot le plus recherché et somme de requete par tranche de 30 minutes");

        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
//      job.setCombinerClass(PriceSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(PriceSumReducer.class);

        job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```